# what permission from `permission_handler` is needed for `nfc_manager`?

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, nfc, user-permissions

I'm using the plugins below

```yaml
  nfc_manager: ^3.1.0
  permission_handler: ^8.1.0
```

with this setup

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-EE)
...
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Pixel 3a (mobile) • 965AY0WP5C • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • macOS (desktop)   • macos      • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.101

• No issues found!
```

if I run

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: Permission.values.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final p = Permission.values[index];
              print(p);
              return Center(child: Text('$p'));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I get the output

```
I/flutter (22369): Permission.camera
I/flutter (22369): Permission.contacts
I/flutter (22369): Permission.location
I/flutter (22369): Permission.locationAlways
I/flutter (22369): Permission.locationWhenInUse
I/flutter (22369): Permission.mediaLibrary
I/flutter (22369): Permission.microphone
I/flutter (22369): Permission.phone
I/flutter (22369): Permission.photos
I/flutter (22369): Permission.photosAddOnly
I/flutter (22369): Permission.reminders
I/flutter (22369): Permission.sensors
I/flutter (22369): Permission.sms
I/flutter (22369): Permission.speech
I/flutter (22369): Permission.storage
I/flutter (22369): Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations
I/flutter (22369): Permission.notification
I/flutter (22369): Permission.access_media_location
I/flutter (22369): Permission.activity_recognition
I/flutter (22369): Permission.unknown
I/flutter (22369): Permission.bluetooth
I/flutter (22369): Permission.manageExternalStorage
I/flutter (22369): Permission.systemAlertWindow
       ⣽I/flutter (22369): Permission.requestInstallPackages
I/flutter (22369): Permission.appTrackingTransparency
I/flutter (22369): Permission.criticalAlerts
I/flutter (22369): Permission.accessNotificationPolicy
```

I'd like to avoid to go through the process of manually adding the permissions
bu I'm not sure which permission from `permission_handler` should I request
to access NFC

can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `permission_handler` plugin to request permission [`android.permission.NFC`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#NFC) because it's **normal** permission, not **dangerous** permission. Simply declare it in `AndroidManifest.xml`, no permission handling is required.

Comment: the android part doesn't worry me much, but the ios part really does

Comment: iOS Setup is mentioned here: https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager#setup. Have you followed that?

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to avoid